# Android JSONArray equivalent of indexOf?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`s called `myArray`, and at some point in my code I retrieved one of the objects. For example:

```
JSONObject myObject = myArray.getJSONObject(x);
```

Later, I'd like to look up the index of `myObject` within `myArray`. That is, I'd like to get x back.

Is there an "indexOf" method in Java/Android?

```
y = myArray.indexOf(myObject); // y should equal x
```

If not, can I loop through `myArray` and directly compare `myObject` to `myArray.getJSONObject(i)` without having to compare every element of the `JSONObject`. In other words, is `myObject` a copy or a reference to an element in `myArray`?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a `net.sf.json.JSONArray.indexOf(Object o)` method but not on Android `org.json.JSONArray` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little test to see what actually happens to JSONObject and JSONArray objects. Maybe it's clear in the documentation, but I didn't see it.

The "get" methods of JSONObject and JSONArray return a *reference*, not a copy. For example, I have a JSONArray myArray of JSONObjects, and I get one of the objects with:

```
myObject = myArray.getJSONObject(x);
```

Since myObject is a reference to the element in myArray, if I modify myObject it's modified in myArray as well.

Furthermore, I can loop through the array and compare the objects directly rather than having to compare each element within the objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++)
    if (myarray.getJSONObject(i) == myObject)
        System.out.println(i + " is equal"); // will be true when i == x
    else
        System.out.println(i + " is not equal");
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no indexOf method you should just loop through it until you get a match.

Actually... java's own ArrayList does the exact same thing

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (elementData[i] == null) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (o.equals(elementData[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you mean I can use the indexOf method of ArrayList on a JSONArray object? How?

Comment: I mean that using an indoxOf method in ArrayList is just as efficient as looping through the JSONArray to fing the index of a value. It does the same thing.